# Identifying an inverse z-transform using Cauchy's theorem

Tags: inverse, cauchy-integral-formula, z-transform

I have the z-transform of a sequence, and I want to find the sequence.

The transform is:

\begin{equation}
V(z)=\frac{z}{2z^2-7z-4}
\end{equation}

Instead of using tables of inverse z-transforms, I thought of using Cauchy theorem, since the formula for the inverse z-transform very familiar to it:

\begin{equation}
v(n)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint V(z)z^{n-1}dz
\end{equation}

So we start, listing up the form of the inverse transform:

\begin{equation}
v(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{z}{2(z-4)(z+\frac{1}{2})}\cdot z^{n-1}=\frac{1}{4\pi i}\oint \frac{z^n}{(z-4)(z+\frac{1}{2})}
\end{equation}

and use the residue theorem, with all poles included:

\begin{equation}
Res(f; z_0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Res(f;-1/2)=\lim_{z\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}(z+\frac{1}{2})\frac{z^n}{(z-4)(z+\frac{1}{2}))}=\lim_{z\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}\frac{z^n}{(z-4)}=-\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n\bigg(\frac{2}{9}\bigg)\frac{1}{4i\pi}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Res(f;4)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 4}(z-4)\frac{z^n}{(z-4)(z+\frac{1}{2}))}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 4}\frac{z^n}{(z+\frac{1}{2})}=4^n\frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{4i\pi}
\end{equation}

So from here, where do the residues fit in the inverse z-transform integral, and how do we complete this procedure?

UPDATE:

Recalling Cauchy's theorem:

\begin{equation}
\oint \frac{f(z)}{z-a}=Res(z_0)2\pi  i,
\end{equation}

where $a$ is simply the pole, so for the two residues, we have:

Series at the residue at pole $z=4$
\begin{equation}
v(n)_{Res(f;4)}=-\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n\bigg(\frac{2}{9}\bigg)\frac{1}{4i\pi}\cdot 2\pi i=-\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n\bigg(\frac{2}{18}\bigg)
\end{equation}

Residue at pole $z=-\frac{1}{2}$
\begin{equation}
v(n)_{Res(f;-\frac{1}{2})}=4^n\frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{4i\pi}\cdot 2\pi i=4^n\frac{2}{18}
\end{equation}

summing these together, we obtain the final answer:

\begin{equation}
v(n)=4^n\frac{2}{18}-\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n\bigg(\frac{2}{18}\bigg)=\frac{4^n-2^{-n}}{9}
\end{equation}

The inverse z-transform (the n-series of the function $V(z)=\frac{z}{2z^2-7z-4}$) is therefore:

\begin{equation}
v(n)=\frac{4^n-2^{-n}}{9}
\end{equation}

Here is a plot of the original function, V(z):

[image]

and this is the plot of the sequence, V(n):

[image]

Comment: Did you try expanding it as a power series in powers of $\,z^{-1}\,$ or using partial fraction expansion?

Comment: Yes, and I got this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365926/two-partial-fraction-approaches-one-is-wrong-the-other-is-right-why

Comment: The first residue limit should be as $\,z\to -\frac12.\,$ Also the two limits are missing a $2$ in the numerator.

Comment: Thanks, the former error was a typo. The result appears the same. The second is corrected. Thanks. There was a calculation error in the second residue however, it should be 8/9, not 1/9. Corrected also.